# Show next class element

Tags: jquery

I have repeatable elements

```
     <input style="display:inline" class="chkClass" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
     <div class="other">
 //something
     </div>

     <input style="display:inline" class="chkClass" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
     <div class="other">
 //something
     </div>
     ....
```

With change of the checkbox I want to show only next "other" class. It doesn`t work:

```
     $('.other').hide(); //hide all "other" elements

         $('.chkClass').live('change', function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                $(this).next('.other').show();
        }
       });
```

Comment: another $('.other').hide() should be inside the function

Comment: do you want to hide and show on check or just show and dont bother to hide if unchecked? because your code should work just fine if you dont want to hide if unchecked unless if you are getting any js error.

Comment: Define "does not work". It works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fUHXz/)

Comment: @Kishore I just want to show next class, it doesn`t matter if other are checked.

Comment: NOTE: As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.

Comment: i dnt think there is something wrong with your code...it works fine as you intended

Comment: @gormit then your code works just fine unless you are using a newer version of jquery if you are then change your .live to .on .live is deprecated.

Comment: I use jQuery v1.7.1, I will try with on()

Comment: @Engineer doesn`t show an element, but if i try with $('.other').show(); it works, it shows all elements, but I need only next one.

Comment: you mean you want to remove all checked values and hide another except the next `.other` ? 
or like this : http://jsfiddle.net/DQDs7/

Comment: @Al-Mothafar Thank you for your answer, I answered to myself here, I find some solution. ;) I don`t know why it doesn`t work on my machine, and it should to work. There are no JS errors in Firebug. Anyway, good website for testing (jsfiddle.net)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get it, but I needed to set ID for every element:

```
    $('.allOther').hide();


    $('.chkClass').on('change', function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
                var array = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
                $('#other'+array[1]).show("slow");

            }
        });

        <input style="display:inline" class="chkClass" id="smthng_<?php echo $counter ?>" type="checkbox" value="1"/>
    <div id ="other<?php echo $counter ?>" class="allOther">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use nextAll with a query

```
$('.chkClass').on('change', function(){
       if($(this).is(':checked')){
          $(this).nextAll('.other:hidden:first').show();
       }
});
```